# How to change the default background color when select a row?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I used kendo ui, when I selected a row; the default background color is pink.
The current code doesn't include any information of when clicking a row then setting the background color.

My question is how can I change it by my requirement? Let's say I want to blue color when I select the row.

```
export class AppComponent {
public gridData: any[] = products;

public checkboxOnly = false;
public mode = 'multiple';
public selectableSettings: SelectableSettings;

constructor() {
    this.setSelectableSettings();
}

public setSelectableSettings(): void {
    this.selectableSettings = {
        checkboxOnly: this.checkboxOnly,
        mode: this.mode
    };
}
}
```

[StackBlize](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cci5sg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color is set by the following CSS rule:

```
.k-grid td.k-state-selected, .k-grid tr.k-state-selected > td {
    background-color: rgba(255,99,88,0.25);
}
```

You can add your own CSS to override it.

You can also override SASS variables to change some colors in the entire application, in this case `$selected-bg` or `$grid-selected-bg`. More info here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-default/customization/